# SpringMVC, null spring beans, servlets and Apache Thrift

Tags: java, spring, servlets, thrift

I have a web application which has a `UserService` to allow for user-related operations.

I can have the `UserService` bean autowired inside any of my `@Controller` classes and it works fine.

If I add a second servlet of type `ThriftServlet` like so:

```
//register the thrift API servlet
ServletRegistration.Dynamic thrift = servletContext.addServlet("thriftapi", new ThriftServlet());
thrift.setLoadOnStartup(2);
thrift.addMapping("/api/*");
```

`ThriftServlet` looks like this:

```
public class ThriftServlet extends TServlet {

    // constructor
    public ThriftServlet() {
        super(new MyService.Processor<ThriftApiHandler>(
            new ThriftApiHandler()), new TBinaryProtocol.Factory());
    }
}
```

And then I decorated my `ThriftApiHandler` with `@Component` to allow for bean injection (or so I thought) so that it looks like this:

```
@Component
public class ThriftApiHandler implements MyService.Iface {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @Override
    public String myServiceMethod(String someParam) throws SomeException, TException {
        // userService is null when this is called by a client application
    }
}
```

I can see in the debug logs that the autowiring is indeed taking place (timestamps and classes snipped):

```
<snip> - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'thriftApiHandler'
<snip> - Creating instance of bean 'thriftApiHandler'
<snip> - Registered injected element on class [my.package.api.ThriftApiHandler]: AutowiredFieldElement for my.package.service.UserService my.package.api.ThriftApiHandler.userService
<snip> - Eagerly caching bean 'thriftApiHandler' to allow for resolving potential circular references
<snip> - Processing injected method of bean 'thriftApiHandler': AutowiredFieldElement for my.package.service.UserService my.package.api.ThriftApiHandler.userService
```

But `userService` (and any other beans I try and inject) is always null inside any of the thrift api methods.

Maybe it's to do with how the `TServlet` class inherits right from `HttpServlet` and doesn't "know" about the spring context?

I feel like I'm missing something to do with servlet contexts and shared beans and so on, but I'm pretty new to SpringMVC. If posting any more code would make this question easier to answer, let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring will always fail (throw exceptions) if it cannot resolve an `@Autowired` target. If you get `null`, then Spring isn't actually managing your object and therefore can't inject anything. That is the case here.

```
public ThriftServlet() {
    super(new MyService.Processor<ThriftApiHandler>(
        new ThriftApiHandler()), new TBinaryProtocol.Factory()); // here
}
```

You are instantiating your `ThriftApiHandler` yourself, instead of getting it from Spring.

If you want to get it from Spring, you will need to get access to the `ApplicationContext` from the `ServlectContext` attributes or wherever else you've put it.

Comment: If I add a `@Component` to the `ThriftServlet`, should I be able to `@Autowire` a `ThriftApiHandler`? Even then, I can't reference it in the `new MyService.Processor<ThriftApiHandler>(thriftApiHandler)` constructor because it's not static...

Comment: @wwarren You shouldn't be adding the Handler in the constructor. Servlets are meant to do their configuration in the `init` method where you have access to the `ServletContext`. `Making your `ThrifServlet` a `@Component` won't change anything if it isn't managed by Spring.

Comment: I think I figured it out - take a look at my answer below and suggest any improvements?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out in the end...

1. Added `@Component` to the `ThriftServlet` class
2. Created a new class called `ThriftProcessor` (see below) which is also a `@Component`
3. Changed the `ThriftServlet` constructor (see below) to be `@Autowired` and accept a `Processor` parameter
4. Tweaked my app initializer class to get the `ThriftServlet` from a spring bean instead of instantiating it myself (NOTE: had to tell the `ApplicationContext` to refresh itself before this would work)

The `ThriftProcessor` class:

```
@Component
public class ThriftProcessor extends MyService.Processor<ThriftApiHandler> {

    @Autowired
    public ThriftProcessor(ThriftApiHandler iface) {
        super(iface);
    }
}
```

The `ThriftServlet` class:

```
@Component
public class ThriftServlet extends TServlet {

    @Autowired
    public ThriftServlet(Processor<ThriftApiHandler> p) {
        super(p, new TBinaryProtocol.Factory());
    }
}
```

New servlet configuration in intializer:

```
//register the thrift API servlet using a spring bean
ServletRegistration.Dynamic thrift = servletContext.addServlet("thriftapi", (ThriftServlet) ctx.getBean("thriftServlet")); // get thriftServlet from springbeans!
thrift.setLoadOnStartup(2);
thrift.addMapping("/api/*");
```

If there's a "better" way of doing this, please say so!

Comment: Yes, as I've said, you need to your beans from Spring context if you want Spring to manage them. What you've done seems good. I would simply change `ThriftProcessor` constructor to simply have the `ThriftApiHandler` parameter, no `ApplicationContext` (unless you have multiple `ThriftApiHandler` beans.

Comment: Oh yes, thanks for that - edited it in to my answer!